# send message when sign in failed

Tags: php, database, authentication

I tried to build a sign-up for a blog I'm creating to get experience with php, but unfortunately I can't seem to get "errors" working and I also haven't found anything useful for me on the internet.

With these functions I want to check if a registration is Valid ( username not already used, confirmation of password is the same, every field is filled)

```
public function isEmpty($username, $password, $pwagain){
 if (empty($username) OR empty($password) OR empty($pwagain)) {
   return true;
 } else {
    return false;
 }
}
public function isAssigned($username)
{
 if (!empty($this->userRepository- 
 >isUsernameAssigned($username))) {
   return true;
 } else {
   return false;
 }
}
public function isNotSame($password, $pwagain)
{
 if ($password != $pwagain) {
   return true;
 } else {
   return false;
 }
}
public function isValid($username, $password, $pwagain)
{
 $hashedpassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 $newUser = $this->userRepository->newUser($username, 
 $hashedpassword);
 $_SESSION['login'] = $username;
 return $newUser;
}
```

Here is the code that declares which error should be given, I don't know how to put them together so that the $errors does not get overwritten or something like that

```
public function sign()
{
 $categories = $this->categoryRepository->allCategories();
 $error = "";
 if(!empty($_POST['username']) AND !empty($_POST['password']) 
 AND !empty($_POST['pwagain'])) {
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $pwagain = $_POST['pwagain'];

 if ($this->signInService->isEmpty($username, $password, 
 $pwagain)) {
   $error = "Please fill in all fields.";
 }
 if ($this->signInService->isAssigned($username)) {
   $error = "Username provided is already in use.";
 }
 if ($this->signInService->isSame($password, $pwagain)) {
   $error = "The passwords do not match.";
 }  
  if ($this->signInService->isValid($username, $password, 
  $pwagain)) {
    header("Location: index");
    return;
  } else {
    $error = "";
  }
 }

 $this->render("user/sign", [
  'error' => $error,
  'categories' => $categories,
 ]);
}
```

That's at the beginning of my sign.php to echo the right error when the sign up's not valid.

```
<?php if(!empty($error)): ?>
<p class="error">
<?php echo e($error); ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I really don't know how to put the if's to get it working, at the moment it immediately puts the user in the database even though the username is already used or the passwords do not match. It also shows none of the (in the controller declared) $errors.

The functions (isAssigned etc) should not be the problem since they've worked before.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Comment: what is the exact problem? do you get an error message when rendering the view? does the view display but the place where the message should be is blank? have you tried checking what print_r outputs for `$error` on both the controller and the view?

Comment: The problem is that I do not get an error-message( the ones I've declared in the controller). The User is put in the database even though the username is already used or the passwords are different.

Comment: if I'm following your code correctly, it appears that the part where you actually insert the user in the database (the call to `$this->signInService->isValid`) is not under any conditional statement so it'll be executed no matter what happens with all the previous validations... give me a couple of minutes to better elaborate a proper answer

Comment: I also changed the isSame() to isNotSame ->if ($password != $pwagain) { return true;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that no matter what happens with the business logic validations (email must be new, user must have entered an email, password and password verification must both be set and not empty) is not driving any decision on your code to *not* call the function that actually creates a new user in the database (`$this->signInService->isValid`) so even if one or more of those validations fail, the insertion is done anyway.

The above raises multiple issues:

1.- if the email must be unique in the database but the insertion succeeds anyway, you should alter your user table and have the field where the email is stored flagged as `UNIQUE` (I'm assuming mySQL, postgres or similar.. not familiar with how other database engines would work). Even if everything else if left the same, this would prevent the new record insertion which, together with the following, would produce an error to be displayed:

```
if ($this->signInService->isValid($username, $password, 
  $pwagain))
{
    header("Location: index");
    return;
} 

else 
{
    $error = "Insertion aborted. Email was duplicated";
}
```

Now, the above is just an additional protection layer for the duplicate email case. You shouldn't just rely on this so:

2.- Only attempt the insertion if all validations have passed. Otherwise skip right into the error output

```
$abort = false;
$error = '';
if ($this->signInService->isEmpty($username, $password, 
 $pwagain)) 
 {
   $error .= "Please fill in all fields.";
   $abort = true;
 }

 if ($this->signInService->isAssigned($username)) 
 {
   $error .= "Username provided is already in use.";
   $abort = true;
 }

 if ($this->signInService->isSame($password, $pwagain)) 
 {
   $error .= "The passwords do not match.";
   $abort = true;
 }

 if ($abort == false)
 {
    if ($this->signInService->isValid($username, $password, 
      $pwagain))
    {
        header("Location: index");
        return;
    } 

    else 
    {
        $error = "Insertion aborted. Email was duplicated";
    }
 }

    $this->render("user/sign", [
     'error' => $error,
     'categories' => $categories,
    ]);
```

what the above does is:
a. first assume all checks will pass, so default to "not aborting" and set an empty error message (this prevents PHP warnings for the first concatenation.. PHP will warn if you are concatenating a string into a previously non-existing variable
b. run all checks. If any of those checks fail, flag the abortion by setting `$abort = true;` and concatenate the specific message to the error variable (so, if multiple checks fail, you can inform them all to the user

c. check if the abort flag is set to true and then decide if attempting the insert or just outputting the errors. This is important because a successful insert sends the user a redirect header, which halts the execution of everything below it (which is why you never got to the error message displaying)

d. finally, if validations passed but the insert failed, upon exiting the final `if` you'll redirect the user to the error output (note that I didn't use an `else` clause precisely to allow that a user input not flagged for abortion can re-join the flow that would have been followed by an abort flag

Comment: First, thanks for your very detailed answer and explanation! Second, it still doesn't work perfectly. It won't send an error when the fields aren't completely filled or completely empty

Comment: I think I know why... fat-fingers-me apparently missed a closing bracket. Let me check

Comment: well I did not? Is it because of the 'OR' ? I don't know if there's a difference between it and || ..

Comment: updated my answer... there was an extra opening bracket above the `header` call. Should work as intended now. And no, PHP handles `OR` and `||` in the same manner internally, so there should be not trouble using either